# Finding the current quarter year in Powershell to rename a file

Tags: powershell, csv, file, datetime

I'm trying to get the current quarter placed in a file name.
I've assigned the year and current quarter number to two different variables so I can use them as I please anywhere as well (such as renaming a folder, to reference a file/folder, etc.)

Current File is:

`FileName.csv`

My code:

```
$QYear = $(Get-date -f yyyy)
$QNum = [int][math]::Ceiling($today.Month/3)
$file1 = “file1.csv”
$file2 = “$QYear-Q$QNum-FileName(distrubution).csv”
Import-CSV $lineCount | Select-Object 'LineCount', 'Name' | Export-Csv $file2 #I was reordering columns
```

Current Output:

`2023-Q3-FileName.csv`

Desired output:

`2023Q3FileName.csv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this string expression:

```
$file2 = "$QYear-Q$QNum-FileName(distrubution).csv"
```

to:

```
$file2 = "${QYear}Q${QNum}FileName(distrubution).csv"
```

By using `{ }` as qualifiers around the variable name, you prevent PowerShell from trying to resolve `$QYearQ` or `$QNumFileName`